# how *.\t can be compared using regular expression?

Tags: c++

```
string str;
if (str = 1.\t) || (str = 2.\t) || ........ || (str = n.\t) {
  // some code
```

}

Basically I have to check int followed by ".\t"

Comment: str = 1.\t ?? Apart from that, can you use any 3rd party libraries ?

Comment: A single-digit int? A backslash followed by a lowercase 't'? Or multiple digits followed by a full-stop and a tab? If you can't describe the problem using words, then describing it in a regular expression is going to be far harder!

Answer (score 1):

Regex you want is `[0-9]+\.\t`

Use Boost.Regex if you need a regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach (without regular expressions), if your string is always an int followed by `.\t`

1. Find the substring `.\t` in the string
2. If you find it, remove it from the string
3. Try converting the string to a number (something like `boost::lexical_cast` as this will throw an exception if it cannot convert the string), failing that, try `strtol` and check that it consumed the full string.

Answer (score 0):

afaik an additional lib has to be used in order to make use of regExp functionality in c++ and boost provides such.
i found the explanations found under [johndcook.com](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html) quite helpful.

Comment: C++11 now provides it in the Standard Lib.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is overkill for this situation.
Try this:

```
bool testIntFollwedByTab(std::string const& test)
{
    std::stringstrean  teststream(test);
    int  num;
    char c;
    return (teststream >> std::noskipws >> num >> c) && (c == '\t');
}
```

- It puts the string `test` into a stream.
- Then we read a number followed by a character from the stream. The manipulator `noskipws` indicates that white space is significant (otherwise leading white space before the number and the character are silently dropped).

  - If this fails (because there is not a number followed by a character) then the bad bit of the stream is set and the stream converts to false and the return statement returns false.
  - If this is successful then we test to see if the character read was a '\t'

Or in normal code (with one line):

```
int num; char c;
if ((std::stringstream(str) >> std::noskipws >> num >> c) && (c == '\t'))
{
    // Do Work
}
```